# YouTube API get viewers list

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to make an app for streams on youtube like twitch coins. Therefore, I need to be able to get a list of current viewers, or at least those who have opened subscriptions or sth like that. Is it possible in the current youtube API? Where can I read about this in docs? I did not find any information on that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]. Please do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no API for getting a list of current viewers for a live video on YouTube.